# Returning different documents by Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, collections, compare, difference

There are two collections. We are trying to find the records that one of the collections has and the other one has not.

Example:

```
Collection_1 
{recordNo: 1},
{recordNo: 2},
{recordNo: 3},
{recordNo: 4},
{recordNo: 5}

Collection_2
{col.num: 1},
{col.num: 2},
{col.num: 3}



Result:    
{recordNo: 4},
{recordNo: 5}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Show the code attempts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
db.getCollection('Collection1').find({
  recordNo: {
    $nin: db.getCollection('Collection2').distinct("col.num")
  }
})
```